# GameKit and Swift: instance property is not an optional but can be nil?

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

`GKTurnBasedParticipant` has a property: `player`, which has class `GKPlayer`. The declaration is written as:

```
var player: GKPlayer { get }
```

Yet the API documentation says,

> The value of this property may be nil if this slot in the match has
>   not yet been filled by an actual player.

So if it can be `nil`, why isn't the declaration:

```
var player: GKPlayer?
```

What am I not understanding here? Is it something with the getter? This is actually important because the player should be `nil` for automatched games where a second player has yet to join.

When I do conditional unwrapping (after migrating to Swift 4.2)

```
if let onlineGKPlayer = participant.player {
```

this now is a compiler error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'GKPlayer'

[image: Screenshot from GKTurnBasedParticipant player]

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkturnbasedparticipant/1521037-player

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when it was updated, but the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkturnbasedparticipant) now lists it as an Optional:

```
var player: GKPlayer? { get }
```

It seems you had the right idea